# Android NDK - Using pre- existing c library for an android app

Tags: java-native-interface

Is it possible to make system calls to  android kernel from the App? Example : system(cmd) is inside of a C program and I am using JNI to access it in my android activity.

Answer (score 0):

The answer: System calls - yes. Calls to system() - kind of.

The two are not the same thing. system calls are provided by the kernel, and Bionic provides a thin wrapper over them, much in the same way as the normal LibC wraps them in vanilla linux.

system(), however, is not a system call, but a function provided by LibC, effectively equivalent to fork(), then execl("/system/bin/sh", "... args") in the child process and wait.

A cursory look at the Android sources showns Bionic doesn't export system(). but you can implement it manually. More importantly, however, is the question why you'd want to do so? Technically, you can load JNI (System.loadLibrary in Java) and then have the native method do whatever - but this would greatly complicate your life, especially considering your application is sandboxed and you can't rely on normal behavior of shell commands (as most are provided by toolbox on the device, if at all).